# Will ubuntu work on my computer?

Tags: home-directory, compatibility

Here are the specs:
Microsoft Windows XP Media Center Edition Version 2002 SP3

Packard Bell.
Intel (R) Pentium (R) D CPU 2.80GHz
1.00 Gb of RAM

Comment: You can try Ubuntu before you install it.  without affecting your system

Answer (score 5):

In theory - yes - is the short answer.  You meet the minimum recommend specifications.

The quickest way to find out is to download the ISO and either burn it onto a CD or write it to a USB stick.

Follow the 1 - 2 - 3 guide on the [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

You can Ubuntu from what is called a *live CD* - if everything looks ok - go ahead and install

- as an installation from windows (this is called a wubi install) - or
- as a side-by-side installation (called a dual boot) - or even
- just say goodbye to windows and wipe your hard-drive clean during installation with a Ubuntu only install.

---

There is more than Ubuntu for you to explore as well (download links below)....

1. [Lubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu)
2. [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)
3. [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu)
4. [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)

Comment: If it turn out that Ubuntu is to heavy / sluggish / slow for your pc you can try a light weight version called xubuntu (http://www.xubuntu.com)

Comment: almost all people forget this version of ubuntu Lubuntu -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu

Answer (score -2):

It will work Although it will be good to update your RAM to 2GB or even 4GB. I had 1.9GHz CPU and it worked fine with 10.04 and I don't think there is much thinks to make it not work! But my advice is install 10.10 and if it performs well upgrade to 11.10.

Comment: What a bad idea to suggest 10.10. This is a release that will not get any security updates anymore from April on.

Comment: You can see a bad idea up until when the computer cannot support Natty (unity) or Gnome3/Unity 11.10. If you read between lines I said that if performance is Optimum he should upgrade. So Yes if machine cannot handle Natty/Oneiric, only option is Maverick or below. And that is not my faulty

Comment: I see your answer is great but wait a minute I didn't knew the specs for Ubuntu and so I proposed doing tests from lower versions upwards. Thanks for downvotes and sorry for this little "protest" ;)